# Kotlin context receivers cannot resolve members of generic type

Tags: kotlin, generics

In the following code, the `call` member of `Animal` cannot be resolved even though `Cat` is specified as context receiver and it has a member named `call`.

```kotlin
interface Animal { val call: String }
object Cat : Animal { override val call: String = "Meow" }
object Dog : Animal { override val call: String = "Woof" }

fun <T : Animal> acquireAnimal(animal: T, block: context(T) () -> Unit) {
  block(animal)
}

fun main() {
  acquireAnimal(Cat) {
    call
  }
}
```

When I type `this` inside the lambda, then the IDE seems to suggest that the type of `this` is `Any?`.

[image: example where "this" with generic context receiver resolves to Any?]

If I do the same with a function without a generic context receiver, then it seems to get the type right.

[image: example where "this" with non-generic context receiver resolves to the correct type]

Is this a limitation that is by design or is this a bug?

Comment: @Tenfour04 it seems like you missed the `context(T)` on the lambda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you cannot access `call` was a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-51243#focus=Comments-27-5994207.0-0), which was fixed in [Kotlin 1.7.20](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1720.html#support-for-kotlin-k2-compiler-plugins).

A [workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-51243#focus=Comments-27-5994207.0-0) for lower versions is:

```
sealed interface TypeWrapper<out A> {
    object IMPL: TypeWrapper<Nothing>
}

fun <T: Animal> acquireAnimal(animal: T, block: context(T) (TypeWrapper<T>) -> Unit) {
    block(animal, TypeWrapper.IMPL)
}

fun main() {
    acquireAnimal(Cat) {
        val x = call // works!
    }
}
```

However, the fact that `this` doesn't work is intended. [Context receivers do not change the meaning of `this`](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/context-receivers.md#referencing-specific-receiver). Since you are in a global function, `this` does not mean anything, and the existence of a context receiver does not change that.

Normally, to access the context receiver itself, you need to do a qualified `this` by appending the generated label for the context receiver:

```
context(Foo)
fun foo() {
    val x = this@Foo
}
```

However, your context receiver is a type parameter, so according to the [rules here](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/context-receivers.md#referencing-specific-receiver), I don't think a label is generated for the context receiver.

Comment: I was only using the auto completion dialog for `this` to get an insight into what the IDE / compiler might be doing. It seems to be fixed with 1.7.20 indeed!